# $("#divElement").html() not adding html data to it

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Returning view from laravel controller to ajax request and populating data to div element, but not working if I insert any other string like `.html("+++++")` or if I use `.text()` it works but `.html("")` and `.html(data)` not working. Type of `success:function(data)` is string also and that string data is html table with laravel default pagination.

**Table Data Receiving from controller in ajax success callback**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <td>Stock Name</td>
      <!-- <td colspan="2">Action</td> -->
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td>book</td>
      <td><a href="http://localhost:8000/shares/1/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>
      <td>
      <form action="http://localhost:8000/shares/1" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="lYeyrbyZpnFLqICDXgpXuqXPVEHX61gjJsWNDIIg">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
      </form>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>

      <ul class="pagination" role="navigation">
      <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="&laquo; Previous">
      <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
      </li>
      <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">1</span></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost:8000/sharesShow?page=2">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="http://localhost:8000/sharesShow?page=3">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="http://localhost:8000/sharesShow?page=2" rel="next" aria-label="Next &raquo;">&rsaquo;</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
```

**Ajax Function**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#searchBtn').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();

           var url = $("#searchForm").attr('action');
           var data = $("#searchForm").serialize();

           $.ajax({
              url: url,
              method: 'get',
              data: {
                "data": data,
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
              },
              dataType: "html",

              success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
                $("#divElement").empty();
                $("#divElement").html(result);
                }
            });
           });
        });
```

**Controller returning statement**

```
    $data = Share::paginate(1);
    return view('shares.showAjax')->with('data',$data);
```

**Div Element**

```
     <div id="divElement">
    </div>
```

Comment: You see to be removing all child nodes with `$("#divElement").empty()`. Is that code accurate?

Comment: that div has already a table in it and I am putting new data in it after a search

Comment: I don't see where you're using `html()` or `text()`.

Comment: I just updated.

Comment: What does `console.log(result);` display?

Comment: that shows the table I mentioned above in the question

Comment: If `result` contains that HTML string and you're using `$("#divElement").html(result)`, then [I can't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/hfmxvs9u/). Can you create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate?

Comment: show your `console.log(result)` data. and where is your `searchForm` and `searchbutton` in `html`